# Getting Nearest records to more different points

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to query nearest records to more different points with using spatial index hint. If I put "and" between them (like first block), there is no problem. But if I use "Or" (like second block), I am getting the error :

> The query processor could not produce a query plan for a query with a spatial index hint.  Reason: Could not find required comparison predicate.  Try removing the index hints or removing SET FORCEPLAN.

What is wrong? Is there any alternative solution?

**First block:**

```
SELECT 
   [Id],[Geocode]
FROM 
   [dbo].[Companies] with (INDEX(SpatialIndex_GeoCode))
WHERE 
   ([Geocode].STDistance(geography::Point(42.7085, -74.9456, 4326)) < 8046.72) 
   and ([Geocode].STDistance(geography::Point(42.7085, -74.9456, 4326)) < 18046.72)
```

**Second block:**

```
SELECT 
    [Id],[Geocode]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Companies] with (INDEX(SpatialIndex_GeoCode))
WHERE 
    ([Geocode].STDistance(geography::Point(42.7085, -74.9456, 4326)) < 8046.72) 
    OR ([Geocode].STDistance(geography::Point(42.7085, -74.9456, 4326)) < 18046.72)
```

Comment: please explain why removing the index hint is not an option

Comment: because of performance. while running query without hint, the index is not used. So query runs very slow

Comment: i posted an answer that includes the hint. does it perform adequately?

Answer (score 2):

you can always separate the two datasets that the `or` produces and then put them back together. using `union` instead of `union all` should avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT 
    [Id],[Geocode]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Companies] with (INDEX(SpatialIndex_GeoCode))
WHERE 
    ([Geocode].STDistance(geography::Point(42.7085, -74.9456, 4326)) < 8046.72) 
union
SELECT 
    [Id],[Geocode]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Companies] with (INDEX(SpatialIndex_GeoCode))
WHERE 
    ([Geocode].STDistance(geography::Point(42.7085, -74.9456, 4326)) < 18046.72)
```